# Is it possible to extend an XSD type?

Tags: xml, xsd

If i have a type defined as

```
<xs:element name="serviceResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="status"/>
                <xs:element ref="info"/>
                <xs:element ref="code"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
```

And would like to have an additional type that defined as

```
      <xs:element name="serviceResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="status"/>
                <xs:element ref="info"/>
                <xs:element ref="code"/>
                            <xs:element ref="level"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

Is it possible to create a new type that extends the first type and only append the "level" element to the new type? (sort of like inheritance in Java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be possible, if only the type of serviceResponse were a named type rather than anonymous:

```
    <xs:complexType name="serviceResponseType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="status"/>
            <xs:element ref="info"/>
            <xs:element ref="code"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="extendedType">
      <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="serviceResponseType">
           <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element ref="level"/>
           </xs:sequence>
        </
     </
   </
```

Comment: +1 because it's a good answer and I enjoyed your XSLT book.